# dns_get_record function fails to retrieve domain details

Tags: php, dns, lookup, nameservers

I'm trying to retrieve domain details of a domain I'm looking up which I purchased and pointed the nameservers to (which was done more than 72 hours ago). Now, when I'm using the `dns_get_record` function to look up the details of my domain, e.g.

```
dns_get_record('www.mydomain.com');
dns_get_record('mydomain.com');
```

They both just return an empty array with no items or values in it, so I cleared my DNS cache, but this didn't seem to solve the problem. I went to [`http://whois.domaintools.com/`](http://whois.domaintools.com/) to look up on their side, I can confirm the domain has the correct nameservers pointed to, but not `dns_get_record` since returning an empty array.

I tried using the `dig` command and `nslookup`, I cannot see the nameservers in the output.

How can I find the nameservers of a domain in PHP?

Comment: w8, I don't understand 1 think... did `dig` and `nslookup` returned a valid response?

Comment: Did you try passing `DNS_ALL` as the second argument to `dns_get_record()`?

Comment: Yup, it still doesn't return anything.

Comment: How long does it take to return nothing? A few seconds or instantly?

Comment: May I ask what the domain in question is?

Comment: I can't find a NS or SOA record for that domain on the public internet, which is probably the cause of the problem. It would seem that the domain does not yet have any valid public DNS entries.

Comment: But in my domain registrar I added my nameservers, surely it should work?

Comment: It should (as long as you have done it correctly) but maybe some internal gremlin in the registrar's system has prevented it from working - you should contact them and ask them what the problem is. All I know is that Google's public DNS `8.8.8.8` does not know anything about your domain's NS or SOA records.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. Recently it worked, then I parked my domains, then couple days later I pointed them back. So overall I should contact GoDaddy?

Comment: I guess so... did you follow [these instructions](http://help.godaddy.com/article/664)?

Comment: Annoyingly those servers don't accept requests from everyone - or at least they don't accept requests from me, at any rate. I think you are going to have to brave the annoying phone systems and talk to someone at GD...

Answer (score 1):

You should wait a bit until the nw domain will propagate through your DNS. This can, in some case, take more than 72 hours.

> Note: you must have a valid DN Server address configured on your host. Try
> with **8.8.8.8 as DNS.**
>
> Note: on Windows it will only works if you have PHP 5.3 or +

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate ;)